# Pagination not working after reinitialize the data-table instance in angular 8

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables-1.10, angular8, angular-datatables

I am trying to paginate data from an array in angular 8, but there is a weird problem I m facing. I am paginating data by dtTrigger as shown in the example https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way but when new data is being added, page numbers not increasing according to the data.

I've tried the rerendering method, but it's not working as expected

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AdminService } from 'src/app/Services/admin.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PagerService } from './Pager.service';
import { PageService } from 'src/app/Services/page.service';
import { AuthServices } from 'src/app/Services/auth.service';
import { Subject, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

declare var $: any;

class DataTablesResponse {
  data: any[];
  draw: number;
  length: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.sass']
})

export class AdminComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild(DataTableDirective, { static: false })
  dtElement: DataTableDirective;
  myTable: DataTables.Api;
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  allData: any = [];
  curr_data: number;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthServices,
    private pageService: PageService,
    private adminService: AdminService,
    private router: Router,
    private pagerService: PagerService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const that = this;
    this.getParamNum();
    this.dtOptions = {
      language: { search: '', searchPlaceholder: 'Search' },
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
      info: true,
      drawCallback() {
        $('.paginate_button.next:not(.disabled)', this.api().table().container())
          .on('click', () => {
            this.api().page(2).draw(false);
            that.getFurtherData();
          });
        $('.paginate_button:not(.disabled)', this.api().table().container())
          .on('click', () => {
            that.getFurtherData();
          });
      },
      columns: [{ data: 'ID' }, { data: 'post_title' }, { data: 'post_status' }]
    };
    this.getData(this.curr_data);
  }

  // ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  //   this.dtTrigger.next();
  // }


  /* Receiving params for initial data */
  getParamNum() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.curr_data = params.curr_data;
      console.log(this.curr_data);
    });
  }

  /* Getting initial data */
  getData(currData: number) {
    this.adminService.getAllData(currData)
      .subscribe(allData => {
        this.allData = allData;
        console.log(this.allData);
        // Calling the DT trigger to manually render the table
        this.dtTrigger.next();
      }, err => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 500 || err.status === 401) {
            this.authService.loggedOut();
          }
        }
      });
  }

  getFurtherData() {
    const lastData = this.allData[this.allData.length - 1];
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/more_data', lastData).subscribe(
      (resp: any) => {
        resp.forEach(elem => this.allData.push(elem));
        console.log(this.allData);
        this.rerender();
      },
      err => console.error(err));
  }

  rerender(): void {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
      const currentpage = dtInstance.page() + 1;
      console.log(currentpage);
      // Destroy the table first
      dtInstance.destroy();
      // Call the dtTrigger to rerender again
      this.dtTrigger.next();
      // dtInstance.page(currentpage).draw('full-hold');
    }).catch(err => console.error('aya re aya', err));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // Do not forget to unsubscribe the event
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

I have to use dtTrigger.next() for incrementing page numbers but when I comment my dtTrigger.next() in rerender method then page incrementing but it reinitializes again the data table and page is set to 1. So that I cannot go to other pages.

Comment: rerender is for re-initialising the table.
Could you please explain how you increment the page with dtTrigger?

Comment: I am incrementing pages by dtTrigger.next() but dtTrigger.next() is rerendering and if i don't use dtTrigger.next() then page number not incrmenting...

Comment: @GaryB
I am incrementing pages by dtTrigger.next() but dtTrigger.next() is rerendering and if i don't use dtTrigger.next() then page number not incrmenting...

Comment: dt.trigger (re)renders the table, my question was how do you increment anything with it?